# Writing data depending on length of array in C++

Tags: c++

I take data from serial port using below code:

```
for (sa = 0; sa < 15; sa++) {
   printf("::%0.2X", buf[sa]);
}
```

I take data that have different length like below. `buf[4]` defines length of array. For example, if `buf[4] == 07` there are 13 elements in array; if `buf[4] == 09` there are 15 elements in array.

Data 1: `::02::03::98::00::07::20::16::09::30::13::15::23::B6::`

Data 2: `::02::03::99::00::09::20::16::09::30::13::15::25::23::00::9C`

I want to write code like above and my integer `LENGTH` will vary depending on the length of `buf[]` array.

```
for (sa = 0; sa < LENGTH; sa++) {
   printf("::%0.2X", buf[sa]);
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you explain why the solution should be something else than the trivial `LENGTH = buf[4] + 6;` ?

Comment: I didn't think.You are right,solution is very simple. @nvoigt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:

```
for(sa=0;sa<buf[4]+5;sa++){
    printf("::%0.2X",buf[sa]);
}
```

If however you only get one element at a time, you can do instead:

```
for(sa=0;sa<4;sa++){
    printf("::%0.2X",buf[sa]);
}
int length = buf[4] + 1;
printf("::%0.2X",length); //prints buf[4]
for(sa=0;sa<length;sa++){
    printf("::%0.2X",buf[sa+5]);
}
```

Comment: I just used the same style as the question

Comment: There is no `buf[sa+5]` in the question or `buf[4]+5`

Comment: if we write `int length = buf[4]+1;` instead of  `int length = buf[4];` ,problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `LENGTH` based on the value of `buf[4]`

```
int length = buf[4] + 6;
```

And then the for loop that you already have.

Comment: it should be `int length = buf[4] + 6;`